# Changing the presentation of a query

Tags: php, html

I have this code to output records from a database

```
<?php
include 'database_conn.php';      // make db connection

$sql = "SELECT filmID, title, categoryName, notes FROM film";

$queryresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryresult)) {
$filmID = $row['filmID'];
$filmTitle = $row['title'];
$filmCat = $row['categoryName'];
$filmNotes = $row['notes']; 

    echo "<div>$filmID, $filmTitle, $filmCat, $filmNotes</div>";
    } 

    mysqli_free_result($queryresult); 
    mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

but to be able to remove commas and format the display of the content I need to change...

```
echo "<div>$filmID, $filmTitle, $filmCat, $filmNotes</div>";
```

to...

```
echo
"<div class="film">
<span class="filmID">5</span>
<span class="title">my darling clementine</span>
<span class="category">epic</span>
<span class="notes">Henry Fonda</span>
</div>";
```

I keep getting an error when submitting the form saying (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/unn_w15025267/public_html/chollerton.php on line 45)

Line 45 is:

```
"<div class="film">
```

Records currently look like this:
Patrick, Bloggs, 15, Blogs Street, Durham, DH2 ABC, 0191 123 4567, 07001212111, patrick&sheila@madeupemail.com, SMS

Quite new to this so any help would be amazing

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please edit it to be more clarified

Answer (score 2):

The correct code would be the following:

```
echo
"<div class='film'>
<span class='filmID'>5</span>
<span class='title'>my darling clementine</span>
<span class='category'>epic</span>
<span class='notes'>Henry Fonda</span>
</div>";
```

As the first double quote starts the string and the next closes the string.
SO `"<div class="film">` is erroneous.

Or you may as well escape the double quote on the inside:

```
echo
"<div class=\"film\">
<span class=\"filmID\">5</span>
<span class=\"title\">my darling clementine</span>
<span class=\"category\">epic</span>
<span class=\"notes\">Henry Fonda</span>
</div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using double quotation inside string literal. It will confuse the parser. Use single quotation instead:

```
echo
"<div class='film'>
<span class='filmID'>5</span>
<span class='title'>my darling clementine</span>
<span class='category'>epic</span>
<span class='notes'>Henry Fonda</span>
</div>";
```

Comment: Alternately, the internal double-quotes can be escaped, eg. `echo "<div class=\"film\">";`  But your answer is better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
echo <<<HERE
<div class="film">
<span class="filmID">$filmID</span>
<span class="title">$filmTitle/span>
<span class="category">$filmCat</span>
<span class="notes">$filmNotes</span>
</div>

HERE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to use the variables you got from the DB, I think this is what you want. This answer also assume there is no PHP above this HTML. If there is you would have to leave PHP parsing (`?>`) before these lines.

```
<div class="film">
  <span class="filmID"><?php echo $filmID; ?></span>
  <span class="title"><?php echo $filmTitle; ?> </span>
  <span class="category"><?php echo $filmCat; ?></span>
  <span class="notes"><?php echo $filmNotes; ?></span>
</div>

<?php
    //resume PHP parsing (if needed)
```